# WebView always brings itself to front on Mobile Devices - Possible Bug

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, gluon, javafxports

In my code I have a webview and on top of it I put another pane with a Label in it, as it shown below.
Although in Windows it works correct and as expected, on mobile platforms (iOS tested) the WebView always comes to front, ignoring the node on top of it. I guess this is a kind of a bug, but I would appreciate any ideas of overcoming this until it is fixed. Thanks in advance. Source code can be downloaded from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109459668/JavaSuns_WebView.zip).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The WebView control on iOS / Android uses the native control, what means that it is part of a OS native layer. See for instance on iOS the WebView [implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/922957ec457e/modules/web/src/ios/java/javafx/scene/web/WebView.java#l1097).

It could have been added in front of the JavaFX layer, or behind the JavaFX layer, and it was z-ordered above all other JavaFX visuals.

In any case it won't take part of the Z-ordering inside the JavaFX layer: ordering any of the JavaFX control/containers won't solve it, it will be always on top of any of them.

The only advice is you should try to avoid adding JavaFX components on top of the WebView, and also avoiding placing the WebView control in a view that allows side popups or dialogs.

Comment: The reason why i want that is because i have a "Loading Pane" in another project that appears on top of everything any time the user is waiting for a page to load or a request to complete. Some users did not realize that they have submitted something through webview cause the "Loading Pane" did not appear. Some others thought that it just hanged up there. It's a problem:)

Comment: Indeed, but you'll need to find a different way, maybe with a progress indicator. Check the `AppBar`, it contains API to show a progress indication while the web view is loading (since 4.2.0).

Comment: Is there a way to load the progress indiciator inside the webview maybe?

Comment: Only if you load it as html content

Comment: Possibly i'll go for that cause i wanna have a consistency with the rest application when waiting. Thanks Jose

Comment: If anything more reliable comes up in the future, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that JavaFX WebView does not take part of the Z-ordering and always appear on top of all others (see Jose Pereda answer), as a temporary solution I decided to hide WebView and show my "Loading Pane" whenever a loading takes place in WebView.

Here is an example how I implemented it in code:

```
public class WebViewController {

   @FXML
   protected WebView webView;

   @FXML
   private void initialize() {
       WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
       webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, oldState, newState) -> {

            webView.setVisible(newState == State.SUCCEEDED);
            loadingPane.setVisible(newState == State.RUNNING);

        });
   } // initaliaze()
} // class WebViewController
```